# Android Actions not Approved by Google

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

Here is my actions.xml file i don't know what happing here i read all the Doc and implement all the stuff but Google says, "The following built-in intents are not triggering as intended:
`actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE`"
For guidance on how to create an actions.xml file, see our developer docs

I don't know what happing with my `actions.xml` file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><actions>
<action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
    <!-- Each parameter can reference an entity set using a custom ID. -->
    <parameter name="feature">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" />
    </parameter>


    <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}"></fulfillment>

</action>

<entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
    <entity
        name="glucose"
        alternateName="@array/alternatives"
        identifier="featureone"
        url="AppRx://glucose/one" />
    <entity
        name="blood_pressure"
        alternateName="@array/alternatives2"
        identifier="featuretwo"
        url="AppRx://glucose/two" />
</entity-set>
<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_HEALTH_OBSERVATION">
    <fulfillment
        fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
        urlTemplate="content://glucose/glucose{?name}">
        <!-- name = "ID_ONE" or "ID_TWO"  -->
        <!-- If no inventory match, name is a text value, such as "Body Temperature" -->
        <!-- (Optional) Use entityMatchRequired="true" to require inventory match for fulfillment -->
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="healthObservation.measuredProperty.name"
            urlParameter="name" />
    </fulfillment>

    <!-- Define parameters with inventories here -->
    <parameter name="healthObservation.measuredProperty.name">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet2" />
    </parameter>
</action>

<entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet2">
    <entity
        name="lastglucose"
        alternateName="@array/alternatives3"
        identifier="featureglucose"
        url="content://glucose/glucose" />
</entity-set>
</actions>
```

Comment: Was there more explanation on why your submission wasn't approved? There should be more explanation about what is missing in your implementation of OPEN_APP_FEATURE.

Comment: Not more explanation only they said this

Comment: Is that my implementation is correct?

Comment: Can you try adding a fallback fulfillment to OPEN_APP_FEATURE as [the sample](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature#derive-fulfillment-url-using-inline-inventory) in the reference docs?